# How to confing a database for multiple users with different data

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm developing a web page where students, after registering, can introduce their school schedule, mark test and calculate averages. My problem is:
how do I do for each user to have their own schedule, calendar etc. I could be simple for you but I'm having difficulties solving this.
[This is how I want schedules menu to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dKEq.png)

all the data introduced for the schedule will show up on the table

Comment: After registering, users should have a primary key. Use that id to attach data to a specific user.

Comment: I'm using email as a primary key. How do I do that, can you teach me or maybe link me a article?

Comment: Andre, this question is too broad because it involves a lot of different pieces --- you are asking how to design a database, how to read from a database, and how to get/display database information on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at how a relational database works.
Everything you're trying to do is use a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO best way to achieve this is to register user ID+name in $_SESSION then, when he reaches the page, retrieve schedule from where it's stored. Depends also on the schedule/calendar format